# Consecutive web requests in Spring WebFlux get null with SecurityContextHolder.getContext()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I am using `WebFlux WebClient` to call 2 REST APIs subsequently. The first API returns a list of products and the second API returns a list of promotions for a products IDs.

`Flux<Product> products = productService.getProducts()`

`List<Prodmotion> promotions = promotionService.getPromotions(product)`

To call my APIs, I use JWT and Keycloak. I added an interceptor to inject the token in each `WebClient`.

I used the clients in separate controllers and endpoints are responding without issues.

My goal is to use the two calls subsequently and get all the promotions for a list of products.

```
productService.getProducts()
              .map(product -> promotionService.getPromotions(product))
              .subscribe(promotion -> System.out.println(promotion.getName()))
```

The problem is, during the second call, the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` method returns `null`.

> 2022-06-30 14:52:48.666+0200 ERROR app [reactor-http-nio-2] [] [r.c.p.Operators.error] - Operator called default onErrorDropped
> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext.getAuthentication()" is null
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext.getAuthentication()" is null

**Edit:** I tried and got the same error:

```
productWebClient.post()
            .bodyValue(Map.of())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Product.class)
            .map(product -> promotionWebClient.post()
                  .bodyValue(Map.of("id", product.getId()))
                  .retrieve()
                  .bodyToFlux(Promotion.class)
             )
             .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

I mean that, the nested call does not have access to the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: Use https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.html

Comment: You are using the blocking way to obtain the user, you should use the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` instead of the classic `SecurityContextHolder`.